# Aggregate by multiple groups and keep the result for each level in R

Tags: r, aggregate, levels, group

Is there any possibility to get expected result in simplest way (without intermediate steps, as I did in my code)?
I was looking for it and couldn't find any solution...

So, for example:

```
df <- data.frame(   A = c("01","01","01","01","01","01","02","02","02","02","02","02"),
                    B = c("12","12","12","12","14","14","18","18","18","22","22","22"),
                    C = c("01","01","02","02","01","02","01","02","05","01","02","02"),
                    D = c("1","2","1","2","2","1","2","1","3","2","1","3"),
              value_1 = c(25,14,1,15,0,15,0,16,18,74,112,36), 
              value_2 = c(2,0,48,12,0,47,95,14,188,65,14,47),
              value_3 = c(78,5,14,26,9,0,4,0,0,8,0,4))
```

I would like to summarise values for each level (A,B,C,D) and combination of them to show the sum of each level in the final table.

```
A <- df %>%
  group_by(A) %>% 
  summarise(across(value_1:value_3, sum))

B <- df %>% 
  group_by(A,B) %>% 
  summarise(across(value_1:value_3, sum))

C <- df %>% 
  group_by(A,B,C) %>% 
  summarise(across(value_1:value_3, sum))

AD <- df %>% 
  group_by(A,D) %>% 
  summarise(across(value_1:value_3, sum))

BD <- df %>% 
  group_by(A,B,D) %>% 
  summarise(across(value_1:value_3, sum))

result <-bind_rows(A, B, C, AD, BD)
result[is.na(result)] <- "00"
result <- result[,c("A","B","C","D", "value_1", "value_2", "value_3")]
result <- result[order(result$A, result$B, result$C, result$D),]
```

My data has much more levels, so how could I do it without making intermediate steps like: B, C.. to get the result like this:

```
> head(result)
# A tibble: 6 x 7
  A     B     C     D     value_1 value_2 value_3
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
1 01    00    00    00         70     109     132
2 01    00    00    1          41      97      92
3 01    00    00    2          29      12      40
4 01    12    00    00         55      62     123
5 01    12    00    1          26      50      92
6 01    12    00    2          29      12      31
```

Is there any possibility to do it with **.groups** argument or using **aggregate** function instead of combination **group_by** and **summarise**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```r
df <- data.frame(   A = c("01","01","01","01","01","01","02","02","02","02","02","02"),
                    B = c("12","12","12","12","14","14","18","18","18","22","22","22"),
                    C = c("01","01","02","02","01","02","01","02","05","01","02","02"),
                    D = c("1","2","1","2","2","1","2","1","3","2","1","3"),
                    value_1 = c(25,14,1,15,0,15,0,16,18,74,112,36), 
                    value_2 = c(2,0,48,12,0,47,95,14,188,65,14,47),
                    value_3 = c(78,5,14,26,9,0,4,0,0,8,0,4))

grp_vars <- list("A", c("A", "B"), c("A", "B", "C"))

library(tidyverse)

map_df(grp_vars,
    ~ df %>%
      group_by(across(.x)) %>%
      summarise(across(value_1:value_3, sum), .groups = "drop")) %>%
  mutate(across(where(is.character), ~ replace_na(.x, replace = "00"))) %>%
  relocate(where(is.numeric), .after = where(is.character))


#> # A tibble: 15 x 6
#>    A     B     C     value_1 value_2 value_3
#>    <chr> <chr> <chr>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
#>  1 01    00    00         70     109     132
#>  2 02    00    00        256     423      16
#>  3 01    12    00         55      62     123
#>  4 01    14    00         15      47       9
#>  5 02    18    00         34     297       4
#>  6 02    22    00        222     126      12
#>  7 01    12    01         39       2      83
#>  8 01    12    02         16      60      40
#>  9 01    14    01          0       0       9
#> 10 01    14    02         15      47       0
#> 11 02    18    01          0      95       4
#> 12 02    18    02         16      14       0
#> 13 02    18    05         18     188       0
#> 14 02    22    01         74      65       8
#> 15 02    22    02        148      61       4
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

if I understood correctly

```
map_df(
  grp_vars,
  ~ df %>%
    group_by(across(.x)) %>%
    summarise(across(value_1:value_3, sum), .groups = "drop") %>%
    mutate(level = paste0(.x, collapse = ""))
) %>%
  mutate(across(where(is.character), ~ replace_na(.x, replace = "00"))) %>%
  relocate(level, where(is.numeric), .after = where(is.character))


# A tibble: 15 x 7
   A     B     C     level value_1 value_2 value_3
   <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
 1 01    00    00    A          70     109     132
 2 02    00    00    A         256     423      16
 3 01    12    00    AB         55      62     123
 4 01    14    00    AB         15      47       9
 5 02    18    00    AB         34     297       4
 6 02    22    00    AB        222     126      12
 7 01    12    01    ABC        39       2      83
 8 01    12    02    ABC        16      60      40
 9 01    14    01    ABC         0       0       9
10 01    14    02    ABC        15      47       0
11 02    18    01    ABC         0      95       4
12 02    18    02    ABC        16      14       0
13 02    18    05    ABC        18     188       0
14 02    22    01    ABC        74      65       8
15 02    22    02    ABC       148      61       4
```

Comment: Thank you, works well!! @Yuriy Is there any possibility to replace NA with the 'level' of aggregating instead of "00" as it is right now? for example the first aggregate level is "A" so it replace all NA with "A" in the row, the second one sth like paste0(grp_vars[[2]][1],grp_vars[[2]][2]) ? Or another solution to create extra column with mutate( level = (.x)) %>%  but it doesn't work this way..

Comment: Great! Please show the expected result